# Displaying random images

Tags: android

im novice to android.For displaying random images i used arraylist.

```
ArrayList<Integer> List = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
        { 
            List.add(i);
            System.out.println("Random Images"+List.add(i));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(List);

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            imageArr[i] = (ImageView)findViewById(id[List.get(i)]);
            System.out.println("Display Images"+List.get(i));
        }
    }
```

it is running correctly in logcat but what should do to display images on emulator screen. Pls Suggest

Comment: Do you expect that the emulator interprets your Sysouts correctly?

Comment: All you are seeing in Logcat is that you are shuffling the ArrayList correctly, it has nothing to do with the images themselves.

Comment: Yeah im getting result properly in logcat.Logcat result is:                                                                 08-23 15:53:07.053: INFO/System.out(453): Random Imagestrue
08-23 15:53:07.053: INFO/System.out(453): Random Imagestrue
08-23 15:53:07.053: INFO/System.out(453): Display Images6
08-23 15:53:07.060: INFO/System.out(453): Display Images1
08-23 15:53:07.103: INFO/System.out(453): Random Imagestrue
08-23 15:53:07.103: INFO/System.out(453): Random Imagestrue
08-23 15:53:07.180: INFO/System.out(453): Display Images5
08-23 15:53:07.180: INFO/System.out(453): Display Images0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an ImageView to display Images on the Screen.
You can display drawable, bitmaps, ... 
The easiest way to do this create your main.xml like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myImageView" />
```

Then call in your code (maybe in the onCreate):

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
```

Then make a Drawable Array or an ArryList with bitmaps, whatever.
Get a Random value (like `Math.random()`) and fetch a random image from array or arraylist like

```
Drawable drawable = drawableArray[YOURRANDOMNUMBER];
```

and set the Drawable to the imageview.

```
imgView .setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a read and see if it helps you: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/